# Number theory problem - contradiction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In an algebraic proof (for my problem it doesn't matter which proof) I have a special setting:

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}, \text{gcd}(a,c)=1,b<c \ \text{and} \ a \in \left\lbrace 1, \ldots , c\right\rbrace$

I tried to make a proof by contradiction and received the following equation
$$ \frac{ab}{c}=d, d \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Now I think this is unpossible because $\text{gcd}(a,c)=1$ and $b<c$ but I am not sure how I should argue exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your rather scarce data, you have a contradiction. If $\;p\;$ is a prime dividing $\;c\;$ , then:

$$\left(\frac{ab}c=d\iff ab=cd\right)\implies p\mid ab\;,\;\;p\nmid a\implies p\mid b $$

Taking the maximal power of each prime dividing $\;c\;$ we get the same as above, but then we'd have that **all** the powers of all the primes that divide $\;c\;$ also divide $\;b\;$ and then $\;b\ge c\;$ , contradiction.

Comment: I think for this contradiction the data is enough.
So your conclusion is the following:
$$p|c \Rightarrow p|b \Rightarrow b \geq c. $$
I think I understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By Euclid's Lemma $\, \gcd(c,a)=1,\, \ c\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, c\mid b,\,$ which is a contradiction if $\,|b| < |c|.\,$ But you assume only that $\,b < c,\,$ so the contradiction  fails if $\,b < 0,\,$ e.g. if $\, b = -c.\,$ But it works if $\,b\ge 0.$

Comment: Yes it fails to use Euclid's Lemma. But the contradiction fails not. I can find no mistake in DonAntonio's argumentation.

Comment: @top The mistake is as I said, if you allow $\, b< 0\,$ then you cannot reach a contradiction. Don's argument is just Euclid's Lemma done a prime-at-a-time. It's more efficient to use Euclid.

Comment: Ok sorry, I think I can assume $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @top Then it is ok. This is essentially *equivalent* to Euclid's Lemma, which can be proved in many ways, e.g. prime factorizations, Bezout's identity, gcd laws, etc.